# Why this simple port scanner hangs?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm making very simple unthreaded Python port scanner:

```
    import sys, socket
  1 
  2 try:
  3     host = sys.argv[1]
  4     print(host)
  5 except IndexError:
  6     print('missing arg')
  7     sys.exit()
  8 
  9 ports = [22, 23, 80, 53, 443, 8080]
 10 try:
 11     for port in ports:
 12         sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 13         socket.setdefaulttimeout(1.0)
 14         result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))  # hangs on this line
 15         print(result)
 16         print(f'Checking port {port}')
 17         if result == 0:
 18             print(f'Port {port} is open')
 19         sock.close()
 20 except KeyboardInterrupt:
 21     print('Exiting ...')
 22     sys.exit()
 23 except Exception as e:
 24     print(str(e))
 25     sys.exit()
```

Before I removed all `print` statements I found out that the script hung on indicated line. The line where simple indication of established connection is made (or not made).

Port scanner is ran against my router by running `python port_scanner.py 192.168.1.254`

What might be an issue here ?

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers unless you need to refer to a line number in the question.

Comment: call `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` before creating the socket. You only need to do this once, not inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `socket.setdefaulttimeout(1.0)` above the `for` loop solved the issue. Thanks goes to @Barmar